# Missing File after C# Rest API dockerization

Tags: c#, docker, image, file, copy

I am building aa rest api with swagger. and i dockerize the project like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine AS final
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs && \
apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./TestProject.API/bin/publish .    
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestProject.API.dll"]
```

but now i added a Resscources to main TestProject.API project with Files in it.
Thes Files are not copied into my dicker image.
i tried a lot to find, whats is actually inside of the image. in seems that the Resscources Folder ist there, but no files are in it.
of course i set the file to "always copy to outputfolder".
and in the build artifacts i see the file is there.

```
RUN ls -la /app/Resscources/
```

this gives no result. But calling this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("TESTSTUFF")]
public IActionResult TESTSTUFF()
{
    var result1 = Directory.GetDirectories(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    var result2 = Directory.GetDirectories("/app/Resscources");

    return Ok(resul1, result2);
}
```

result1 returns all directorys  including the Ressources Folder
result2 returns nothing.

when i try

```
COPY /app/Resscources/ /app/Resscources/
```

the dockerize process failed because nothing is found. i don't get it